# What's the best way to fetch Bootstrap popover content with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that shows a "special buttons" on front-end via WordPress shortcode.
I'm using Bootstrap 4, these buttons use Bootstrap popovers and I need to retrieve/fetch popovers title and content from a database without refreshing the page so I need to use Ajax.
I read that using an asynchronus Ajax call is deprecated (it can slow down the page) so what's the best way to use Ajax with Bootstrap popovers?

**EDIT: following Alex_89 reply, I wrote:**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    // read EDIT 2 for working version...
} );
```

**EDIT 2:**
*...after many tests now **seems to work!***

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    let buttons_with_popover = $( 'button[data-gdpr-popover="true"]' );

    buttons_with_popover.popover( {
        container: 'div.my-container',
        html: true,
        placement: 'top',
        title: '<div class="d-flex justify-content-between font-weight-bolder"><span class="header-text">Please wait...</span><span class="close-popover float-right ml-3"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span></div>',
        content: '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><div class="spinner-border text-success" role="status"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div></div>',
        trigger: 'click'
    } );

    buttons_with_popover.on( 'shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $( '.close-popover' ).on( 'click', function () {
            buttons_with_popover.popover( 'hide' );
        } );

        let this_button = $( this );
        this_button.data( 'popover_id', this_button.attr( 'aria-describedby' ) );
        let popover_id = this_button.data( 'popover_id' );
        let popover_header_text = $( '#' + popover_id + ' h3.popover-header span.header-text' );
        let popover_body = $( '#' + popover_id + ' div.popover-body' );

        $.ajax( {
            type: 'post',
            url: ajax.url,
            data: {
                action: 'queries_database',
                _nonce: ajax.nonce,
            },
            success: function ( queried_data ) {
                let options = $.parseJSON( queried_data ).options;

                popover_header_text.html( options.popover_title );
                popover_body.html( '<div><p class="text-justify">' + options.popover_body + '</p></div>' );

                this_button.popover( 'update' );
            },
            error: function () {
                popover_body.html( '<p class="text-warning">Ops! Something is wrong... <i class="far fa-tired"></i></p>' );
            }
        } );
    } );

    buttons_with_popover.on( 'hidden.bs.popover', function () {
        $( 'div.ccwhatsapp-container .popover' ).remove();
    } );

} );
```

Comment: Not sure where you read this thing about (asynchronous) AJAX calls, but that's plain wrong. It's neither deprecated, nor discouraged. Maybe someone wanted to advise against using synchronous AJAX calls interrupting the script and got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a snippet for a simple **AJAX** request that displays the *result* inside a **Bootstrap Popover**. It should serve as a sample for what you want to achieve. BTW, I don't know who would say that async AJAX requests are a bad practice, let alone deprecated. As @Damocles told you, that's just plain wrong.

**JQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    let popoverBtn = $("#popover-button");
    let dataProviderURL = "url-to-your-wp-data-provider-function";

    popoverBtn.popover({
        title: "your-popover-title",
        placement: "top",
        html: true,
        content: "<div id='popover-body'><img src='path-to-your-preloader' alt='Loading...'></div>"
    });

    popoverBtn.on("shown.bs.popover", function () {
        $(".popover-close-btn").click(function () {
            popoverBtn.popover("hide");
        });

        let popoverTitle = $(".popover-header");
        let popoverBody = $(".popover-body");

        $.ajax({
            url: dataProviderURL,
            type: "GET",
            data: {id: "some-identifier-for-the-data-you-want-to-retrieve"},
            success: function (result) {
                popoverTitle.html(result.title);
                popoverBody.html(result.content);
                popoverBtn.popover("update");
            },
            error: function () {
                popoverBody.html("<em class='text-danger'>some-error-message.</em>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In this snippet, the initial content inside the popover's body is a **preloader**, an animated icon to indicate that the data is being loaded (it's a good practice to always provide some feedback to the user), but it's not a *must*. You can just leave it blank.
I suggest you review the [Popper.js Documentation](https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html) for the different *events* you can attach your functions to.

Comment: I'll try this snippet and I'll let you know if it is right for me, thank you!

Comment: I edited my question, can you try to help me, please?

Comment: Why don't you do the AJAX request using "GET" instead of "POST"? Also, did you check the console output in the browser? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you're using the wrong selectors to obtain a reference to the popover's "header" and "body" tags. I edited my answer. Use the popover's classes to obtain a reference to them instead of an id.

Comment: I tried multiple way (id, class, ecc...) I have not errors but popover content is not updated after it is shown with initial "loading..." content

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Could you please accept my answer as the solution? Thanks.